# Check if a string/line that is going to write into a text file is already exist in the text file

Tags: java, file-io, duplicates, distinct

I am analyzing a web access log and try to find out all the unique object (any file or any path) that were requested only once in the access log.  Every time the program write into the text file, the content of the text file looks like this :

```
/~scottp/publish.html
/~ladd/ostriches.html
/~scottp/publish.html
/~lowey/
/~lowey/kevin.gif
/~friesend/tolkien/rootpage.html
/~scottp/free.html
/~friesend/tolkien/rootpage.html
.
.
.
```

I want to check if the line which is going to write into the text file is already exist in the text file. In order words, if it's does exist in the text file, then do nothing and skip it and analyze the next line. If not, then write it into the text file.

I tried to use `equals` or `contains` but it doesn't seems to be work, here's a little pieces of my code:

```
        // Find Unique Object that were requested only once
        if (matcher3.find()) {
            if(!requestFileName.equals(bw.equals(requestFileName))) {
                bw.write(requestFileName);
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
```

What should I do to actually perform a check ?

Comment: It's very hard to help with this tiny, out of context code snippet. But what's sure is that `requestFileName`, which is most probably a String, will never be equal to the boolean value returned by `bw.equals(requestFileName)`. And `bw`, which is probably a BufferedWriter, will never be equal to `requestFileName` which is a String. You need to store the lines in a Set, and check if the next line is contained in the Set before writing it to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JB Nizet commented you should make use of Set

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/yourFile.txt")));

String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    // duplicate
    if(set.contains(line))
        continue;

    set.add(line);

    // do your work here

}
```

Comment: Why Set<Integer>? hashCodes are not unique. You should have a Set<String>, and store the lines inside, not their hashCode. Also, continue sucks. Just use `if (!set.contains(line)) { set.add(line); // do your work }`.

Comment: for not to keep all Strings in the jvm heap

Comment: Then you'll have a program consuming less memory, but being incorrect. Try being correct first. Optimize after, and only if needed, and without compromising the correctness.

Comment: why did you find this answer 'incorrect', I am sure it is correct and optimized

Comment: Well, then, you're wrong. How many possible Strings can exist? An infinity. How many possible hashCodes can exist? Only 2^32. What do you conclude? An infinity of Strings have the same hashCode. So your code will prevent some strings to be written to the file although they are different from any other written strings, just because they just share the same hashCode.

Comment: that is the same case for `Set<String>`. isn't it?

Comment: No. A Set<String> stores Strings. A String that is different from any other String in the Set will be added to the Set, even if it has the same hashCode as one of the strings in the set. See http://ideone.com/Eux56R for a simple example.

Comment: Many thanks @JB Nizet, you are totally right. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something simple like this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourFilePath))) {
    boolean lineExists = false; 
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (currentLine.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(requestFileName.trim())) { 
            lineExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();

    if (!lineExists) {
        bw.write(requestFileName);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) { 
    // Do what you want with Exception...
}
```